# Среднее абсолютное отклонение MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Не особо много информации на данную тему.
Как это реализовать без подзапроса (я до них ещё не дошёл)?

-- В таблице bus_logs хранятся данные о прибытии автобусов на остановки.
-- В поле diff содержится разница в секундах относительно контрольного времени прибытия.
-- Положительные значения говорят о том, что автобус прибыл рано, отрицательные, о том, что он опоздал, 0 – приехал вовремя.
-- Получите список водителей, которые в среднем опаздывают или опережают график на 30 секунд и более.
-- Итоговая таблица должна состоять из двух колонок: driver_id с номером водителя и avg_diff со средним отклонением.
-- Среднее отклонение следует округлить до целого числа.
-- PS. В данном задании следует использовать среднее абсолютное отклонение.

```
SELECT driver_id, ABS(ROUND(AVG(diff), 0)) as avg_diff  
FROM bus_logs
GROUP BY driver_id  
HAVING avg_diff <= -30 AND avg_diff >= 30
```

Вот что я попытался, но получил пустоту...
Мне нужно что-то наподобие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3. И почитайте справу о форматировании своих сообщений.

Comment: окей, изучаю))
сам не в восторге от того, что получилось

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `HAVING avg_diff <= -30 AND avg_diff >= 30` число не может быть одновременно больше 30 и меньше -30. Во-вторых, округлённое среднее абсолютное отклонение будет `ROUND(AVG(ABS(diff),0))`

В итоге:

```sql
SELECT driver_id, ROUND(AVG(ABS(diff),0)) as avg_diff  
FROM bus_logs
GROUP BY driver_id  
HAVING avg_diff >= 30
```